# Increase virtual HDD space on VMWare for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, gparted

I am having an issue following instructions on how to increase from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56443/how-to-increase-the-disk-space-of-a-vmware-virtual-disk).
I cannot get the unallocated space to merge with the sda1, no matter what I try. I allocate the 30GB, then try it that way, but it still doesn't work. I copied sda1 into unallocated -- still didn't work!
I can decrease size of sda1, but cannot increase it.

I've done:

1. Shut down VM
2. From settings change disk sizze
3. in CD/DVD setting, load the Ubuntu ISO
4. Start VM, press F2 to get in bios, and change Boot to CD first
   5/ Run ubuntu as guest
5. sudo apt-get install gparted
6. Run gparted

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right tools in place to do what you want.  The two steps you need to take are to move the extended disk to the end of the unallocated space, then you can grow `/dev/sda1`.  Until you move the swap space out of the way, then you cannot make `sda1` bigger.

From the screen that you have up:

1. Select the extended partition `/dev/sda2`.  It includes `/dev/sda5`, your swap space.
2. Menu `Partition` -> `Move` then move it to the end of the allocated space.
3. Then select the Primary partition: `/dev/sda1`.
4. Menu `Partition` -> `Resize` then grow it to the end of the (newly positioned) unallocated space.
5. Then Apply to make the changes take effect

   `#include <std/disclaimers.h>`

Make backups first, your mileage may vary, RTFM, may destroy your system.

Comment: Given that the extended partition contains only swap space, it would be simpler (and faster) to just delete `/dev/sda2` (incl. `/dev/sda5`), extend `/dev/sda1`, and then create `/dev/sda2` as swap at the end of the disk.   BTW, don't forget to edit the swap entry in `/etc/fstab`

Comment: **You are right, cas!**  There is more than one way to do it.  Editing /etc/fstab is a level of complexity that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Thank you , that worked!